# How to fix 1709 - Index column size too large. The maximum column size is 767 bytes. in mysql in XAMPP

Tags: mysql

I'm importing a new table as Users, into my database but it is showing an error

## 1709 - Index column size too large. The maximum column size is 767 bytes.

I am having
Server version: 10.1.16-MariaDB
PHP version: 7.2.14
phpmyAdmin Version : Version information: 4.8.4

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email_show` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `email_confirmed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `iso2` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `dob` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0=> Not Specified,1=> Male, 2=> Female',
  `phone_show` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `phone_confirmed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `country_id` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `state_id` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `city_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `confirmation_code` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_by` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_by` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `options` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `confirmed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `phone_code` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `provider` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `provider_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `remember_token` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `company_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `portfolio` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `opening_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `closing_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `education` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `notary_number` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `monday_opening_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `monday_closing_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `thuesday_opening_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `thuesday_closing_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `wednesday_opening_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `wednesday_closing_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `thursday_opening_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `thursday_closing_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `friday_opening_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `friday_closing_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `saturday_opening_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `saturday_closing_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `sunday_opening_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `sunday_closing_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `users_email_unique` (`email`),
  KEY `users_country_id_index` (`country_id`),
  KEY `users_area_id_index` (`state_id`),
  KEY `users_created_by_index` (`created_by`),
  KEY `users_updated_by_index` (`updated_by`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=33 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

MySQL said:

## 1709 - Index column size too large. The maximum column size is 767 bytes.

Comment: We need to see the indexes in the create table statement the code isn't complete.. But most likely it one of the `varchar(255)` column which give you that error because of the utf8mb4_unicode_ci  collate.. Which can need up to 4 bytes per character.

Comment: Hello sir, thanks for suggestion. Complete sql table code has been re-edited. I have change collation of db from utf8_general_ci to utf8mb_unicode_ci and re import it but still no effect on table creation

Comment: That's an awful lot of columns. Consider using a JSON column fro things like opening/closing times instead of 14 different TIME columns.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Answer (score 1):

In the last line of the creation table code try changing this:

```
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=33 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

To this:

```
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=33 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```